# forbidden error when post to API rest

Tags: javascript, python, django, rest

i have a web chatbot application that i created using Django and REST for the API. so i want when the press ENTER the entered text will be POST to the API under the name 'request'.

So far this is my code in index.js:

```
$('.message-submit').click(function() {
    insertMessage();
    var post_data = {
               csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
               request : $('.message-input').val()};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/api/",
       data:  post_data,
      dataType: "application/json"
  });
});
```

But the error ""POST /chat/api/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58" in red keeps coming up. I've used many solution such as:

```
  1.csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
  2.@csrf_exempt
```

and non of them in working!! someone minion that i'm missing :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['example.api.auth.AlwaysRootBackend']
```

any solution?

Comment: HTTP response code 403 is an authorization error created by the server. You will need to tell us more about your backend.

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/ You should create a csrf token through javascript and set that as requestheader with the AJAX request as explained in the docs.

Comment: @Timo i didn't set up and authentication bake end

Comment: @1GDST thank you i'll try it

Comment: Where you able to solve it? If yes, please let me know how